# FxCop warning occurs while dependency property in my uwp project

Tags: uwp, dependency-properties, readonly, fxcop

In my project i have used dependency project as in the below code snippet.

```
 public bool ShowAllDay
 {
       get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowAllDayProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ShowAllDayProperty, value); }
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowAllDay.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
 /// </summary>
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowAllDayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowAllDay", typeof(bool), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnShowAllDayChanged));
```

it occurs the following warning ,how i can clear this?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CA2104  Remove the read-only designation from 'MyClass.ShowAllDayProperty' or change the field to one that is an immutable reference type. If the reference type 'DependencyProperty' is, in fact, immutable, exclude this message.

Comment: Why does `DependencyProperty` need to be `readonly`?

Comment: It seems there is no issue  code in your code. if the project can run, you can ignore it.

Comment: Hi Jayden,
There is no issue in this code and i can able to run but i am following MSDN code standard. So when i am using above code ,getting [CA2104](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182302.aspx) this warning.